# ¿Obtener el nombre de una clase en Angular?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, angular5

Estoy trabajando con ***Angular 5***.

Le estoy pasando un objeto a un componente, con el decorador @Input():

```
@Input() x: any;
```

Este objeto puede ser de la clase Xxx, la Yyy o la Zzz.

¿Puedo saber dentro del componente si el objeto recibido es de una u otra clase?

Answer (score 1):

Si realmente es una clase, puedes usar `instanceof`:

```js
let a= [];

console.log('¿Es un array?', a instanceof Array);

class Ejemplo {

}

a= new Ejemplo();

console.log('¿Es un Ejemplo?', a instanceof Ejemplo);
console.log('¿Es un array?', a instanceof Array);
```

Esto no funcionará si el tipo declarado es una `interface` o `type`, porque sólo existen en tiempo de compilación (son conceptos de Typescript, no es Javascript).

Comment: Interesante. Había encontrado una solución válida con Angular2: `console.log( propertyName.constructor.name );`

Comment: Esa solución es similar, la diferencia es que ignora la herencia. No es *de Angular*, sigue siendo algo nativo de Javascript